# Minimizing quadratic function subject to quadratic equality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Given $N \times N$ positive (semi)definite matrix $\mathbf{A}$, vector $\mathbf{b} \in \Bbb C^N$ and $c > 0$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^N}{\text{minimize}} & \mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + 2 \Re\left\{ \mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{x} \right\}\\ \text{subject to} & \mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}=c\end{array}$$

How do I solve this optimization problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a convex optimization problem as written, because $x^Hx=c$ is not a convex constraint. It describes the surface of a hypersphere, which is not convex.

The constraint $x^Hx\leq c$ would be convex, on the other hand. If that relaxation is acceptable to you, then just solve that instead; it's a simple quadratic program. If you *need* equality, then one thing you can do is solve the convex form first. If the global minimum *happens* to achieve $x^Hx=c$, then you're done; the solution is the same for your problem and for the convex, relaxed problem. Otherwise, you need to do something else...

What else *can* you do? Well, it turns out that the $x^Hx \leq c$ version of the problem can be solved globally *even if $A$ is not positive semidefinite*, and therefore non-convex. It is known as the *trust region subproblem*, so it has been studied extensively; Google is your friend here. So I think what you *may* be able to do is adapt the standard Lagrange multiplier technique, which is what is used for the trust region subproblem, for your case. The Lagrangian is

$$L(x,\lambda) = x^HAx + 2\Re{b^Hx} - \lambda( c - x^H x )$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. The optimality conditions are

$$\begin{gathered}
2 ( A + \lambda I ) x + 2 b = 0 \\
x^H x = c
\end{gathered}$$
So when $A+\lambda I$ is invertible,
$$x=-(A+\lambda I)^{-1}b, \quad x^Hx = \| (A+\lambda I)^{-1} b \|_2^2$$
Now you're reduced to searching over the scalar variable $\lambda$ for the value which achieves $x^Hx=c$. Once you have that, then you have your $x$.

Now just to be clear, I don't have an existence proof for you. If you successfully find a $\lambda$, then you should be good. I just don't know if this will always work. For the standard trust region subproblem, it does.

EDIT: I realized that perhaps you're daunted by the complex variables here. Well, there's no need to be; this is easily translated to a real equivalent:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_{\bar{x}} & \bar{x} \bar{A} \bar{x} + 2 \bar{b} ^T \bar{x} \\
\text{subject to} & \bar{x}^T\bar{x} = c
\end{array}$$
where
$$\bar{x}\triangleq\begin{bmatrix} \Re{x} \\ \Im{x} \end{bmatrix} \quad
\bar{A}\triangleq\begin{bmatrix} \Re{A} & \Im{A} \\ -\Im{A} & \Re{A} \end{bmatrix} \quad
\bar{b}\triangleq\begin{bmatrix} \Re{b} \\ \Im{b} \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I understand the translation  between real domain and complex domain. I too think searching for $\lambda$ is the way to go. Do you think this is someway related to waterfilling techniques. Can I apply semi-definite relaxation here?

Comment: btw, a big fan of CVX, and use it extensively in my work. It's a privilege to meet you here.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I see no reason to do anything more complicated here than what I suggest. I say just do bisection on $\lambda$ until you achieve $x^Tx=c$. Don't do relaxation; this is likely to give you the global result, so why screw it up with an approximation?